# Invalid signed-request: Missing required parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instagram, instagram-api

I got the following `response` while getting my Photo from `Instagram`. Please help any help would be appreciated.

```
{ 
code = 403;
    "error_message" = "Invalid signed-request: Missing required parameter 'sig'";
    "error_type" = OAuthForbiddenException;
}
```

Here is my code

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=...........aef2"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {            
   if (error){
        }
        else {   
            NSString * a = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSDictionary *tokenData = [jResponse objectWithString:a];
            NSLog(@"%@",tokenData);

        }
    }];
```

Comment: 1) So send the required parameter.  2) You probably should assume UTF8 encoding, not ASCII.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled `Enforce Signed Requests`, so it requires you to have `sig` parameter which is signature for API request, described here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/

Either generate the signature or disable `Enforce Signed Requests`

Looks like you are making API call from an app (client side), so it is not recommended to make signed request, since u have to save the `client_secret` in the app code. It is recommended to do this on the server to be secure. So just disable the `Enforce Signed Requests` for you app and make API call as is.

Answer (score 2):

A continution for @krisrak answer.

To disable Enforce Signed Requests.

Goto https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Select your **Client** required. **Go to Security**.Uncheck the **Enforce signed requests**

And save the updated changes.